# pip install pandas couldn't find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pip, mapr

while I'm trying to install pandas , getting below error .

can you please suggest me to get solved ?

[mapr@csdssqwqasw22 ~]$ pip install pandas
Downloading/unpacking pandas
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pandas
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pandas
Storing debug log for failure in /home/mapr/.pip/pip.log

Comment: That looks like some sort of network error.  Can you access that page using your browser?

Comment: Actually I'm trying to install in hadoop cluster . I believe there is no problem with the network connection . IS there any other dependency  missing

Comment: Please don't believe, just check it. You could e.g. use  `ping pypi.python.org` and see if the server responds...

Comment: yeah sorry .. it was not responding to pypi.python.org .i was accessing cluster with putty , though it was connected to newtwork . I'm not able to ping any url .. Or else shall I try with Anaconda ?